# Access string's characters from array of pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am new to programming and have faced this particular problem:

```
int *FindLine(char *lines[100],int line_number) {
  char **pointer=lines;
  int i,*stack,counter=0;
  stack=(int*)calloc(30,sizeof(int));
  for (i=0;i<line_number;i++)
    if (*pointer[i]=='{') { 
      stack[counter]=i+1;
      counter++;
    }
  return stack;
}

main(){
  char *line[100];
  FILE *fp;
  char FileName[20];
  char Buffer[100];
  fp=fopen(FileName,"r");

  while(fgets(Buffer,100,fp)!=NULL) {        
    line[i]=strdup(Buffer);                    
    i++;
  }            
  NumOfLines=i;
  Stack=FindLine(line,NumOfLines);
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

stack is supposed to have stored the number of the line each '{' appears in , instead it only stores it if '{' is the first char on the line. is there a way on C to access every single individual character of the strings pointed by the pointers in the array of pointers to strings ?

Comment: Use `malloc` instead of `calloc`. Did not calloc allocate memory on the stack (function scope memory)? Hence one cannot return it outside.

Comment: @JoopEggen - no. `calloc` does not allocate memory from the stack. It allocates it the from the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (*pointer[i]=='{')
```

to

```
if (!strchr(pointer[i],'{'))
```

You may need to add

```
#include <string.h>
```

at the beginning.

`pointer[i]` points to the string (array of chars).
`*pointer[i]` gives you the first character of the string.
So your if condition checks only the first character.

So you have to use [strchr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html)

strchr checks if the '{' char is there anywhere in the string. returns the pointer to first occurance if found or `0`/`NULL` if not found.